# Determine field types for simple schema in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, simple-schema

Is there a way with simple schema in meteor to tell what the type of the different fields are? I know that I can type the following to get the schema:

```
Answers.simpleSchema().schema()
```

This will give me an object of all the fields. Say I have a field called "image" which is a string- there is a key in the image object called "type" which is a function:

```
function String() { [native code] }
```

The function type does change to Number() as I'd expect, when I try to type Answers.simpleSchema().schema().image.type() though, it comes back empty.  Is there a better way to determine the field type for all of my fields in my schema? I need to do convert field inputs to strings vs numbers as appropriate and this seems the best way to do it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple-schema's [clean method](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#cleaning-data) to automatically do type conversions (ex: string to integer) saving you potentially a lot of code.

```
mySchema.clean(obj)
```